# Android studio SDK Updates site link has an error as IO exception while downloading manifest

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I was getting an connection timeout error even if i have decent good internet connection.After spending some more time for finding solution for it i ended up on this problem . on File>>settings>>Android SDK>>SDK update sites>> the error is as follows:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cI07.png)

I have also tried updating all things also installed latest android studio version.
also tried disabling firewall.and checking network connections